# Ubuntu Disks cant detect my Android but MTP works and ADB detects it

Tags: usb, android, mtp

I am running Ubuntu 17.04. With new update of Ubuntu, Disks stopped detecting my android phone. With Ubuntu 16.10 it worked fine. 
I have installed gMTP and it works fine with android, I have run ADB with USB debugging on and it also list it when I run `adb devices`.
But it doesnt show in nautilus nor in Disks.
I cant understand what went wrong.
P.S.All my pendrives works absolutely fine in all the ports. So it is not port problem.